# Can I access nuxt context in nuxt.config.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxt-i18n

I'm using [nuxt-i18n](https://nuxt-community.github.io/nuxt-i18n) and [@nuxtjs/auth](https://auth.nuxtjs.org/) and I want to config the `auth.redirect` option to support i18n like this:

```js
// nuxt.config.js

export default {
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/auth',
    'nuxt-i18n',
    // ...
  ],
  auth: {
    redirect: {
      home: localePath('/dashboard'),
      // ...
    },
  },
  // ...
};
```

Normally, just like `this.$store`, I can access that `localePath` function provided by [nuxt-i18n](https://nuxt-community.github.io/nuxt-i18n/basic-usage.html#nuxt-link) through app instance or the `context` like `this.$localePath` or `app.localePath`. But how can use it inside the `nuxt.config.js` file?

Answer (score 1):

In case of @nuxt/auth module with i18n redirection support problem, I've found a workaround: https://github.com/nuxt-community/auth-module/issues/1116#issuecomment-824814739.

Credit [@azrikahar](https://github.com/azrikahar)

Comment: Any other solutions?, i need to access $i18n inside nuxt.config.js